# Data structure for representing a calendar schedule with a set time granularity?

Tags: java, data-structures, maps

I've been trying to think of a purely Java way to represent a schedule for a whole calendar year. Each schedule is for a 30 minute slot (half hour granularity).

This would be abstracted through a repository methods like `findByDateTime()`

Essentially I need to model time slots at 30 min granularites for each day.

The way I have hacked it together is like so

```
public Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Programme>> enumerateMapOfMapSchedules() {

    int numberOfSlots = 48; //48 half hours in a day

    Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Programme>> dayToTimeScheduleMap = new HashMap<>();

    //create a key value map for each day of the year
    for (int i = 1; i < 366; i++) {

        Map<Integer, Programme> dayProgrammeScheduleMap = new HashMap<>();

        for (int y = 1; y < numberOfSlots; y++) {
            dayProgrammeScheduleMap.put(y, null);
        }

        dayToTimeScheduleMap.put(i, dayProgrammeScheduleMap);
    }
    //creates a map with 365 days and each day having a map of 48 schedule slots
    return dayToTimeScheduleMap;
}
```

I appreciate this solution doesn't handle or have a concept of year, however since these are for mocks/tests then I am ok with this.

Also it doesn't handle a schedule that overlaps, if programme spans two half hour slots.

My query method is quite simple for finding what is in a particular schedule slot.

```
public Programme findByDateTime(LocalDateTime dateTime) {

    int scheduleSlot = dateTime.getHour() * 2;

    //if its the after 30 minute schedule slot
    if (dateTime.getMinute() > 30) {
        scheduleSlot++;
    }

    return scheduleMap.get(dateTime.getDayOfYear()).get(scheduleSlot);
}
```

However for iterating through all the data structure to see how many occurences of a particular programme exist.

My question, is there an easier way of doing this?

I tried doing it with a relational DB but it was hard to represent time periods easily without a lot of SQL.

Any suggestions or implementation advice welcomed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Days vary in length

A calendar schedule only makes sense in the context of a time zone and a year. Politicians frequently change the offset used by the time zone(s) of their jurisdiction. This means days are not always 24-hours long. Anomalies such as [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) mean a day might be 23 hours long, 25 hours long, or something else such as 23.5 hours long.

## Start at the beginning, count by 30-minute increments

So if what you want is to chop up the entire year in 30-minute segments, you must start at the first moment of the first day of a specific year in a specific time zone, and add 30 minutes at a time until reaching the new year.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
Year year = Year.of( 2021 );
LocalDate firstOfYear = year.atDay( 1 );
ZonedDateTime start = firstOfYear.atStartOfDay( z );
List < ZonedDateTime > zdts = new ArrayList <>();

Duration duration = Duration.ofMinutes( 30 );
ZonedDateTime zdt = start;
while ( zdt.getYear() == year.getValue() )
{
    zdts.add( zdt );
    // Setup the next loop.
    zdt = zdt.plus( duration );
}
```

Return a non-modifiable copy of that list.

```
List < ZonedDateTime > slots = List.copyOf( zdts );
```

When run. Notice [what happens](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/canada?year=2021) at 1 or 2 AM on Mar 14, 2021 and Nov 7, 2021.

> slots = [2021-01-01T00:00-05:00[America/Montreal], 2021-01-01T00:30-05:00[America/Montreal], 2021-01-01T01:00-05:00[America/Montreal], 2021-01-01T01:30-05:00[America/Montreal], 2021-01-01T02:00-05:00[America/Montreal],
>
> …
>
> 2021-03-14T01:00-05:00[America/Montreal], 2021-03-14T01:30-05:00[America/Montreal], 2021-03-14T03:00-04:00[America/Montreal],
>
> …
>
> 2021-11-07T00:30-04:00[America/Montreal], 2021-11-07T01:00-04:00[America/Montreal], 2021-11-07T01:30-04:00[America/Montreal], 2021-11-07T01:00-05:00[America/Montreal], 2021-11-07T01:30-05:00[America/Montreal], 2021-11-07T02:00-05:00[America/Montreal],
>
> …
>
> 2021-12-31T22:00-05:00[America/Montreal], 2021-12-31T22:30-05:00[America/Montreal], 2021-12-31T23:00-05:00[America/Montreal], 2021-12-31T23:30-05:00[America/Montreal]]

### Future projections unreliable!

But beware: politicians frequently change the offset used in a zone! This happens much more often than you likely realize. Politicians have even gotten worse at this reducing their forewarning from years to a few months, or even several weeks as seen recently in Turkey and Morocco, and even no forewarning at all as seen in North Korea.

So **you cannot reliably project into the future** using the approach seen above.

## Slot math

I suppose you could approach the slots-of-year problem in another way. Calculate the number of whole slots during the year this way.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
Year year = Year.of( 2021 );
LocalDate firstOfYear = year.atDay( 1 );
ZonedDateTime start = firstOfYear.atStartOfDay( z );
ZonedDateTime end = start.plusYears( 1 );

Duration slotLength = Duration.ofMinutes( 30 );
long wholeSlotsInYear = Duration.between( start , end ).dividedBy( slotLength );
```

Then you could jump to a point in the year by multiplying duration, and adding the result to the start of year.

```
int slotNumber = 22;
Duration jump = slotLength.multipliedBy( slotNumber - 1 );  // Subtract one to change an ordinal number into a zero-based index. 
ZonedDateTime slot22 = start.plus( jump );
```

## Appointment book tracking

If you are doing appointments such as at a hair salon or dental clinic, the usual approach is to track a year-month-day with a particular time of day. But track the time zone separately. So use a `LocalDateTime` with a separate `ZoneId` in your Java model. In your database table, use a pair of columns, one of type akin to the SQL-standard type `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` and another column of a text type holding the name of the time zone such as `America/Montreal` or `Africa/Tunis`.

When building a schedule, apply the zone to determine a moment. In Java, that means applying a `ZoneId` to a `LocalDateTime` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

You need to be clear on the fundamental idea that a `LocalDateTime` object does *not* represent a moment. In our example here, 3 PM on the 23rd of next year could mean 3 PM in Tokyo Japan or 3 PM in Toledo Ohio US, two very different moments several hours apart. A `LocalDateTime` is inherently ambiguous. Thus the need to store a time zone as well, but kept separate.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of( 2021 , 1 , 23 , 15 , 0 , 0 , 0 ) ;
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z ) ;  // Determine a moment.
```

See that same moment in UTC by extracting a `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
```